# Receive a TCP packet and put it in Openssl BIO_mem

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, openssl

I want to receive a TCP packet using socket fd and put it in Openssl BIO. The following code:

```
char buffer[256];
n = recv(fd, buffer, 256, 0);
BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
int y = BIO_puts(bio, buffer);
```

But it receive n = 227 bytes and it put only y = 3 bytes in bio. How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably `BIO_puts` stops at the first 0 byte, because it's designed to be used with C strings.

Comment: So what is your suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @Heil_Me - Use [`BIO_write`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_read.html), which takes a pointer and a length. It should look something like `BIO_puts(bio, buffer, n)`. You should also check the return value from `recv` to ensure it does not fail. Otherwise, `n` will likely be `-1`, which gets promoted to `0xffff...ffff`.

Comment: @jww: I think you meant `BIO_write(bio, buffer, n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) and [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau). My problem solved as they said with this following code:

```
BIO_write(bio, buffer, n)
```